# How to fix this line breaks?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im creating a new file which has the data from other file, and i have to add extra information. The code runs okay but  when i open the file the data that i add messes up the file structure.

```
def writeSalary(fileName):
    f = open(fileName,"r")
    g = open("Personas2.txt","w")
    for line in f:
        line=line[:-1]
        g.write(line)
        g.write("1000\n")
    f.close()
    g.close()
```

The expected output is:

Pedro Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 22 M ESP EDP 1000
Juan Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 21 M ITA CSC 1000
Federico Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 32 M ITA TELEFONICA 1000
Javier Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 35 M ITA TELEFONICA 1000
Manuel Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 27 M ESP EDP 1000
Pelayo Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 60 M ESP TELEFONICA 1000
Luis Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 45 M GER CSC 1000
Ana Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 30 F ESP CSC 1000
Caterina Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 24 F ITA CSC 1000
Isabel Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 29 F ESP TELEFONICA 1000
Covadonga Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 18 F ESP TELEFONICA 1000
Sonia Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 66 F ESP EDP 1000
Alejandra Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 20 F ITA EDP 1000
Pedro Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 20 M ITA ED 1000

But it is:

Pedro Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 22 M ESP EDP 1000
 1000
Juan Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 21 M ITA CSC 1000
 1000
Federico Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 32 M ITA TELEFONICA 1000
 1000
Javier Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 35 M ITA TELEFONICA 100
 1000
Manuel Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 27 M ESP EDP 1000
 1000
Pelayo Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 60 M ESP TELEFONICA 1000
 1000
Luis Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 45 M GER CSC 1000
 1000
Ana Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 30 F ESP CSC 1000
 1000
Caterina Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 24 F ITA CSC 1000
 1000
Isabel Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 29 F ESP TELEFONICA 1000
 1000
Covadonga Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 18 F ESP TELEFONICA 1000
 1000
Sonia Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 66 F ESP EDP 1000
 1000
Alejandra Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 20 F ITA EDP 1000
 1000
Pedro Gonzalez Diaz 71977689X 20 M ITA ED 1000

Comment: Have you considered that your linebreaks in `fileName` may be `\r\n` instead of just `\n`?

Comment: `g.write(line.strip() + " 1000\n")` instead of your 2 lines ... you do not remove the newline+linefeed fully on the original line

Comment: I've tried it but the output its the same

Answer (score 1):

Just change `line=line[:-1]` to `line=line.rstrip()`.

Comment: Unbelievable) And what `print(f"<{line}>")` gives you, if put right after `rstrip()`?

Comment: I havent tried anything like that because i have to write a new file so the prints doesnt help me that much.

Comment: That was for me to see the output. Having string between `<>` we will see if there are forgotten line breaks.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was just that there was an extra line break,so it always printed the 1000, but thank you anyways man